# RestKit + MagicalRecord + Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, restkit

RestKit is compatible to MagicalRecord, however it requires some sort of hack to get it working:

> See: [RKMagicalRecord / RKMRAppDelegate.m @ L15-L18](https://github.com/blakewatters/RKMagicalRecord/blob/master/RKMagicalRecord/RKMRAppDelegate.m#L15-L18)
>
> ```
> // Use a class extension to expose access to MagicalRecord's private  setter methods
>
> @interface NSManagedObjectContext ()
> + (void)MR_setRootSavingContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context;
> + (void)MR_setDefaultContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)moc;
> @end
> ```

So they're using a somewhat hacky approach to acces the private `MR_setRootSavingContext` method.

I know that in swift I can define extensions, but then I have to implement them, how can I achieve the same workaround in swift.

Or more generally, how can I setup Magical Record to use the `NSManagedObjectContext` created by RestKit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply (not good maybe) it's create a bridge file

and add there

```
@interface NSManagedObjectContext ()
+ (void)MR_setRootSavingContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context;
+ (void)MR_setDefaultContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)moc;
@end
```

Here example for create a bridged file
http://ios-blog.co.uk/tutorials/how-to-create-an-objective-c-bridging-header/

Answer (score 0):

what you need to do define a header file with name `NSMangedObjectContext_MagicalRecordify`

with content:

```
@interface NSManagedObjectContext ()
+ (void)MR_setRootSavingContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context;
+ (void)MR_setDefaultContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)moc;
@end
```

then in your bridging header filer, import:

`#import "NSMangedObjectContext_MagicalRecordify.h"`

then you can access those private methods in your swift file.